# Calculating required sample size for an hypothesis test regarding a proportion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size, statistical-power

Suppose we have the null and alternative hypotheses regarding a proportion

$H_0: p = p_0$

$H_a: p \ne p_0$

If we assume that $p$ takes the value $p_1$, what sample size do we need for a z-test of the null hypothesis at the $\alpha$ level with power $1 - \beta$?

Comment: What test do you plan to use?  The power depends on that.

Comment: What is $p_1$?  What is $p_0$? The power depends on that.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica arbitrary numbers between 0 and 1.

Comment: Then you will need arbitrarily different sample sizes.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica obviously

Answer (score 1):

The z-test based on the normal approximation rejects the null when the test statistic is greater than $z_{1 - \alpha/2}$,

$\big|{\frac{\hat{p} - p_0}{\sqrt{p_0 (1 - p_0) / n}}\big|} > z_{1-\alpha/2}$

Or, equivalently,

$\big|{\frac{\hat{p} - p_1}{\sqrt{p_1 (1 - p_1) / n}}\frac{\sqrt{p_1 (1 - p_1)}}{\sqrt{p_0 (1 - p_0)}} - \frac{p_1 - p_0}{\sqrt{p_0 (1 - p_0) / n}}\big|} > z_{1-\alpha/2}$

With $z = \frac{\hat{p} - p_1}{\sqrt{p_1 (1 - p_1) / n}}$, we have

$\big| z \frac{\sqrt{p_1 (1 - p_1)}}{\sqrt{p_0 (1 - p_0)}}  - \frac{p_1 - p_0}{\sqrt{p_0 (1 - p_0) / n}}\big| > z_{1-\alpha/2}$

or equivalently,

$\big| z   - \frac{p_1 - p_0}{\sqrt{p_1 (1 - p_1)/n}}\big| > z_{1-\alpha/2} \frac{\sqrt{p_0 (1 - p_0)}}{\sqrt{p_1 (1 - p_1)}}$

When $p = p_1$, $z \sim N(0,1)$ asymptotically, and the asymptotic power of the test is therefore equal to

$1 - \beta = \Phi\left(  \frac{\sqrt{n}|p_1 - p_0|  - z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{p_0 (1 - p_0)}}{\sqrt{p_1 (1 - p_1)}}  \right) + \Phi\left(  \frac{-\sqrt{n}|p_1 - p_0|  - z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{p_0 (1 - p_0)}}{\sqrt{p_1 (1 - p_1)}}  \right)$

Typically the second term on the right of the equation is quite small, and so we can approximate

$1 - \beta = \Phi\left(  \frac{\sqrt{n}|p_1 - p_0|  - z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{p_0 (1 - p_0)}}{\sqrt{p_1 (1 - p_1)}}  \right)$

Taking the inverse of the normal on both sides,

$z_{1-\beta} =  \frac{\sqrt{n}|p_1 - p_0|  - z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{p_0 (1 - p_0)}}{\sqrt{p_1 (1 - p_1)}} $

Solving for $n$,

$n = \left(\frac{z_{1-\beta}\sqrt{p_1 (1 - p_1)} +  z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{p_0 (1 - p_0)}}{p_1 - p_0}\right)^2 $

Answer (score 1):

One approximation to the power function is to use the p-value function.  The p-value for a score test of $H_0: p\le p_0$ vs $H_a: p > p_0$ is

$$H(p_0;\hat{p})=1-\Phi\bigg(\frac{\hat{p}-p_0}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}}\bigg).$$

At the minimum detectable effect $\hat{p}_{MDE}$ the p-value testing $H_0:p\le p_0$ equals the alpha level of the test, $H(p_0;\hat{p}_{MDE})=\alpha$.  For a given $n$ this p-value function evaluated at any other value $p$ is approximately equal to the power of the test,

$$1-\beta(p)\approx H(p;\hat{p}_{MDE})=1-\Phi\bigg(\frac{\hat{p}_{MDE}-p}{\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}}\bigg),$$

where the minimum detectable effect is $\hat{p}_{MDE}=p_0+z_{1-\alpha}\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}$.

This can be numerically solved for the sample size $n$.  This approach can be simplified even further by inverting a Wald test,

$$1-\beta(p)\approx H(p;\hat{p}_{MDE})=1-\Phi\bigg(\frac{\hat{p}_{MDE}-p}{\sqrt{\hat{p}_{MDE}(1-\hat{p}_{MDE})/n}}\bigg),$$

where the minimum detectable effect is $\hat{p}_{MDE}=p_0+z_{1-\alpha}\sqrt{\hat{p}_{MDE}(1-\hat{p}_{MDE})/n}$.  This is particularly useful in more complicated model.  Of course for a binomial proportion the power of a test can be solved exactly by identifying the rejection region of the test and then evaluating the complementary CDF of the binomial distribution under the alternative.

[Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/350055507_Decision_Making_in_Drug_Development_via_Inference_on_Power) is a paper discussing inference on power as well as approximating power using a p-value function.